# Is there a way to wait in UIViewController class while a dispatch_async thread is executing in another class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have an UIViewController class and i just call a method from a new class called dispatch_thread i created that uses dispatch_async. Below is the .h and .m code for the class dispatch_thread.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface dispatch_thread : NSObject
+(void)addNumber:(int)number1 withNumber:(int)number2 andCompletionHandler:(void (^)(int result))completionHandler;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

#import "dispatch_thread.h"

@implementation dispatch_thread


    +(void)addNumber:(int)number1 withNumber:(int)number2 andCompletionHandler:(void (^)(int result))completionHandler{
        int result = number1 + number2;
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^
        {
            int i=1000;
            while (i>0)
            {
            NSLog(@"doing something in class...%i",i);
                i--;
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
            {
                NSLog(@"callback in class...");
                completionHandler(result);
            });
        });
    }
    
    @end
```

On the UIViewController class i call this method with the code below.

```
[dispatch_thread addNumber:5 withNumber:7 andCompletionHandler:^(int result) {
        // We just log the result, no need to do anything else.
        NSLog(@"The dispatch from class finished ...%i",result);
    }];
//this line should run only after dispatch async finishes.
NSLog(@"Continue after dispatch_async finished ...");
```

The problem is that the line `NSLog(@"Continue after dispatch_async finished ...");` executes in UIViewController class before the dispatch_async finishes.
Is there a way for the UIViewController class to wait for the dispatch async to finish somehow? Any help appreciated.

Comment: What you're asking is how to make an asynchronous operation synchronous.  This is an anti-pattern.  Simply do whatever work you need to do when the task is complete in the completion handler block.

Comment: Your `UIViewController` is running its code on the Main Thread.  You do not want to pause the Main Thread while work is happening on an asynchronous queue that my dispatch to another thread.   If you *did* want to wait on the block to complete you could use `dispatch_sync` but you should **not** do that from the main thread.

Comment: What is the problem to write inside completion handler?

Comment: You could look at the new Swift Async/Await feature. This doesn't make asynchronous code synchronous, but it does let you write your code with an apparently linear flow.

Answer (score 0):

In your code :

```
// this will dispatch code to be executed in some time
[dispatch_thread addNumber:5 withNumber:7 andCompletionHandler:^(int result) {
    // We just log the result, no need to do anything else.
    NSLog(@"The dispatch from class finished ...%i",result);
}];
// You get here as soon as you told the
// you have dispatched some code :
// this code execute before disptched code
NSLog(@"Continue after dispatch_async finished ...");
```

What you need is that the completion handler you pass to dispatch_threads do what you want to do after completion of the thread.

Comment: I was thinking about that and i guess this is the only way. I just wanted to know if there is a way to stop at the MainViewController outside of the block!